# R problem with randomForest classification with raster package

Tags: r, raster

I am having an issue with randomForest and the raster package. First, I create the classifier:

```
library(raster)
library(randomForest)

# Set some user variables
fn = "image.pix"
outraster = "classified.pix"
training_band = 2
validation_band = 1
original_classes = c(125,126,136,137,151,152,159,170)
reclassd_classes = c(122,122,136,137,150,150,150,170)

# Get the training data
myraster = stack(fn)
training_class = subset(myraster, training_band)

# Reclass the training data classes as required
training_class = subs(training_class, data.frame(original_classes,reclassd_classes))

# Find pixels that have training data and prepare the data used to create the classifier
is_training = Which(training_class != 0, cells=TRUE)
training_predictors = extract(myraster, is_training)[,3:nlayers(myraster)]
training_response = as.factor(extract(training_class, is_training))
remove(is_training)

# Create and save the forest, use odd number of trees to avoid breaking ties at random
r_tree = randomForest(training_predictors, y=training_response, ntree = 201, keep.forest=TRUE) # Runs out of memory, does not allow more trees than this...
remove(training_predictors, training_response)
```

Up to this point, all is good. I can see that the forest was created correctly by looking at the error rates, confusion matrix, etc. When I try to classify some data, however, I run into trouble with the following, which returns all NA's in `predictions`:

```
# Classify the whole image
predictor_data = subset(myraster, 3:nlayers(myraster))
layerNames(predictor_data) = layerNames(myraster)[3:nlayers(myraster)]
predictions = predict(predictor_data, r_tree, type='response', progress='text')
```

And gives this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, , value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
(keeps going like this)...
```

However, calling predict.randomForest directly works fine and returns the expected `predictions` (this is not a good option for me because the image is large, and I cannot store the whole matrix in memory):

```
# Classify the whole image and write it to file
predictor_data = subset(myraster, 3:nlayers(myraster))
layerNames(predictor_data) = layerNames(myraster)[3:nlayers(myraster)]
predictor_data = extract(predictor_data, extent(predictor_data))
predictions = predict(r_tree, newdata=predictor_data)
```

**How can I get it to work directly with the "raster" version?** I know that this is possible, as shown in the examples of [predict{raster}](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf).

Comment: Without data, this is not easily solved. I got similar errors when my training set and my test set did not have the same factor levels, and that was often due to some wrong conversion (numeric vars interpreted as factor, or numerics that were stored as character due to some mistake in the data). I'd try to figure out what exactly goes in and out. predict.raster does quite some manipulation, so it might be that there something does not work as expected.

Comment: As you see in the code, the training data consists of a class (factor) i.e. 125,126,127,128,129... and 26 numeric variables i.e. 0 to 32768 (16-bit channels). As I say, the classifier object is created correctly, and when I call predict.randomForest directly using data in a matrix rather than using RasterLayer data and Raster's predict, it outputs the correct predictions... I think the problem might be related to NA's creeping in somewhere, but I can't pinpoint where. Is there a test that I could use to rule this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try nesting predict.randomForest within the writeRaster function and write the matrix as a raster in chunks as per the pdf included in the raster package.  Before that, try the argument 'na.rm=TRUE' when calling predict in the raster function.  You might also assign dummy values to the NAs in the predict rasters, then later rewriting them as NAs using functions in the raster package.

As for memory problems when calling RFs, I've had a plethora of memory issues dealing with BRTs.  They're immense on disk and in memory! (Should a model be more complex than the data?)  I've not had them run reliably on 32-bit machines (WinXp or Linux).  Sometimes tweaking Windows memory allotment to applications has helped, and moving to Linux has helped more, but I get the most from 64-bit Windows or Linux machines, since they impose a higher (or no) limit on the amount of memory applications can take.  You may be able to increase the number of trees you can use by doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in the end, I found that calling predict.randomForest recursively for groups of lines of the image is faster than calling the "Raster" version of predict, so problem avoided for now.